# ArcGIS server javascript export feature to shapefile identified by unique id

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, geoprocessing

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 application which has a map (using ArcGIS server 10.2 and JavaScript) as integral part of it. In that application, user draws a polygon object on the map and puts necessary attributes. Now I want to get that feature in **archived shapefile** which was drawn by the user (based on GUID or OBJECTID which I already have).

To get the shapefile, I published a geo-processing service using "Featureclass to Featureclass" but it fails all the time:

```
function exportShape() {
    alert("job started");
    var gp = new Geoprocessor("http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services/ExportToShape/GPServer/ExportObjToShape");
    var params = { where_clause: "OBJECTID = 231" };
    gp.submitJob(params, gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus, gpJobFailed);
    alert("job submitted");
}
function gpJobStatus(jobInfo) {
    console.log(jobInfo.jobStatus);
}
function gpJobComplete(jobInfo) {
    alert("completed");
}
function gpJobFailed(jobInfo) {
    alert("failed");
}
```

I get messages "job submitted" and "completed" but I never get the message "Failed", however when I check the console then I see the message esriGpFailed

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In it, you'll see the focus on asking *one* question, but once the chit-chat is removed, you have three or four. Please [Edit] this question to focus on one question, and provide details, like the exact version of ArcGIS, and the exact JSAPI, and the exact JavaScript code, and the exact service code and properties (you've left out pretty much *everything* -- it might help to find a highly rated JavaScript question and see how it was structured)

Comment: thanks for your comments. I'd removed other two questions

Comment: Still too brief. Software versions? Exact code? HTTP traffic?

Comment: you've got an extraneous `'` in your where clause. Try `var params = { where_clause: "OBJECTID = 231" };`

Comment: Sorry, that was just typo error in my question. its correct in my code